# When the timer end - return to ResultActivity

Tags: java, android

can you help me wtith problem. When timer is end, user moves to ResultActivity (for example). Here's code

```
       @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        times.setText("Time is up");
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format(
                "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                        - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        .toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                        - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        .toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        times.setText(hms);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start Activity using intent in the onFinish() . You can also put extras in it.

```
@Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format(
                "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                        - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        .toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                        - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        .toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        times.setText(hms);
    }
  @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        times.setText("Time is up");
        Intent resultActivityIntent= new Intent(currentActivityName.this, ResultActivity.class);
        startActivity(resultActivityIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call Start activity from onFinish()

```
@Override
        public void onFinish() {
            times.setText("Время вышло");

    //Start Activity 
    Intent intent= new Intent(activityName.this, ResultActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
        }
```